# Работа с данными полученных по GET от сервера, через js

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django

Я пытаюсь настроить фильтр, который будет проверять был ли ранее создан чат между конкретными пользователями. Я отправлял данные через форму со страницы и так же дополнял эти данные ajax запросом, путем проб и ошибок было выявлено, что request с формы приходит в метод, который и будет отфильтровывать, раньше чем данные ajax, это вызывало ряд ошибок, тем самым пришлось отказаться от отправки через форму прибегнув к event.preventDefault() и пользоваться только ajax. Теперь фильтрация проходит успешно, но перехода на url, который следует после фильтрации естественно не происходит. Вопрос в следующем, я вижу что сервер возвращает get с тем url на который должен произойти переход, могу ли я через js получить адрес этого url и выполнить переход уже в success? Если нет, то могу ли я из полученных get данных извлекать интересующие меня параметры? Например я в get передаю id нужного мне чата в контексте, могу ли я его извлечь из параметров data?

Метод фильтрации чатов:

```
class ObjectDialogMixin:
    model = None
    modelForm = None
    template = None
    templateForm = None
    modelLK = None
    modelUser = None

    def get(self, request):
        ctx = {}
        lk = self.modelLK.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        ctx['lk'] = lk
        chats = self.model.objects.filter(members__in=[request.user.id])
        ctx['unread_chat'] = chats.model.objects.unread_chat(user=request.user).count()
        ctx['user'] = request.user
        ctx['chats'] = chats
        ctx['chatForm'] = self.modelForm
        return render(request, self.template, ctx)

    def post(self, request):
        if request.is_ajax():
            chats = self.model.objects.filter(members__in=[request.user.id])
            form = self.modelForm(request.POST)
            user_one = request.POST.get('user_one')
            user_two = request.POST.get('user_two')
            if user_one and user_two:
                first = self.modelUser.objects.get(id=user_one)
                second = self.modelUser.objects.get(id=user_two)
                chat = self.model.objects.filter(members=user_one, type=self.model.DIALOG).filter(
                    members=user_two, type=self.model.DIALOG)
                if chat:
                    chat_id = chat.last().pk
                    return redirect(reverse(self.templateForm, kwargs={'chat_id': chat_id}))
                else:
                    if form.is_valid():
                        new_chat = form.save(commit=False)
                        new_chat.type = 'D'
                        new_chat.members.set(first, second)
                        new_chat.save()
                        chat_id = chats.last().pk
                        return redirect(reverse(self.templateForm, kwargs={'chat_id': chat_id}))
            else:
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                    chat_id = chats.last().pk
                    return redirect(reverse(self.templateForm, kwargs={'chat_id': chat_id}))
```

Ajax:

```
function CreateChat(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var block_members = document.getElementById('id_members');
    var input = block_members.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i].checked) {
            arr.push(input[i].value);
        }
    }
    console.log(arr);
    if (arr.length === 2) {
        $.ajax({
           url: '/dialogs/',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {
               user_one: arr[0],
               user_two: arr[1]
           },
           success: function (data) {
               console.log('Диалог');
               console.log(window.location.href);
           }
        });
    }else {
        $("#chat-form").on("click", function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/dialogs/',
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    console.log('Чат');
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

После обработки POST запроса мне нужно получить url GET и выполнить переход через js, как это сделать?

```
 "POST /dialogs/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
 "GET /dialogs/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 33072
```

Answer (score 0):

Задачу решил следующим образом:

```
success: function (data) {
               console.log('Диалог');
               console.log(window.location.href);
               var chat_id = data.match(/data-chat-id="(.+?)"/);
               console.log(chat_id[1]);
               var url = document.location.href;
               document.location.href = url + chat_id[1] + '/';
           }
```

Я выяснил, что входящие данные приходят в текстовом формате и через регулярку забрал нужный мне id чата, потом сделал перенаправление на нужный мне url.